# In Windows font shows Italic, but linux it always show bold

Tags: linux, windows, qt

I've created a Qt application and using FontLoader set a font which is proper and as expected in Windows Qt Creator, but when the same thing is run in Linux (Ubuntu) machine it is always been seen as bold/regular a combination of both, can somebody suggest me how to see the same font display both in Linux and Windows OS? 
[image: In Linux]

[image: Windows Image]

```
FontLoader {
    id: localFont;
    source: "fonts/LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf"
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code. A A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Added both the images the id localFont.name property is been used in the other qml to set the font.

Comment: is italic font installed ?

Comment: Yes it is installed and the source from where it is picking is also proper

Comment: Have you tried setting `font.italic: true` on the text element? (yes, it's actually not reporting the italic subfamily)

Comment: Thank you Velkan ,This worked but my actual problem is not solved, I take any other font, it is regular in Windows, same font it shows semi bold in Linux

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue myself Thanks for @Velkan which led me to check different options.

```
font.weight: "Extra Light"
font.weight: "Regular"
font.weight: "SemiBold"
```

Setting the above property gives me the relevant display wherever required.